# Problems with environment variables

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

Since the last time I updated my computer, my environment variables got screwed for some reason(the PATH variable didn't exist), and I set them back for java and maven. The tools that I currently use, and I have a problem with all other variables such as ping, rm,copy etc. How do I get these standard commands back?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) and [vlaurie.com](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm), the default value is:

`C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem`

But that doesn't include modifications by third-party apps.

Comment: you mean I should include that in my PATH variable ?

Comment: Yes, it should have at least that.

Comment: I did set it .. but still nothing is happening, however I did set it from win enviroment, I'll try now with command line

Comment: Any program that uses the PATH needs to be restarted.  So consider restarting the computer after setting it in the GUI.  You don't need to set it in multiple places.